# indexerror: index out of bounds with iloc

Tags: python, pandas

Whenever I use pandas sql for queries in mysql and the result is only one row I'm having trouble selecting values from it.

my command is:

```
result = psql.read_frame("select id,name,age from tb1 where id=1", con=conn)
```

Then it returns a dataframe. However I want to be able to do:

```
age = result['age']
```

But this isn't possible because it is a dataframe. (it creates a index of the rows, so here 0) So I want to make it an series or dict, when I do:

```
result = result.iloc[0]
```

I get

```
{'id': 1, 'name':'john','age':46}
```

When I try:

```
result = result.iloc[0].to_dict()
```

it works but I get an error IndexError: index out of bounds.

How can I just create a series or dict of this single row dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Just include the column selector in `loc`, using ':' to indicate all columns:

```
result = result.iloc[0, :].to_dict()
```

Assumes row zero is the one you wish to convert to a dict.

Comment: it returns the same error when using the columns indicator.